# View has no propType for NativeProp RCTView.borderTopRadius of native type number

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I am getting this error 'View has no propType for NativeProp RCTView.borderTopRadius of native type number' when I run react-native run-android in react native. It seems on my android emulator. Is there any solution ? I triedc all the things on the net but it did not work.
Error goes like this..(If you have not changed this prop yourself,this usually means that your version of the native code and javascript code are out of the syc. Updating both should make this error go away)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a new issue, starting on May 15th, and see the issue on github.https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/19259

edit *app/build.gradle*

```
compile ("com.facebook.react:react-native:your-react-native-version") { force = true } // From node_modules
```